# wxSqlLite3 in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, sqlite, wxwidgets

I have a question how can I use [wxSqlLite](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/wxsqlite3/) in my wxWidgets applications? I downloaded wxSqlite3 for wxWidgets 2.9x and build it but only static win32 debug win32 and static win32 release win32 compiled without errors. How can I add wxSqllite to my project? My ide is visual c++ 2008.

Comment: What configuration do you want to build with? What errors do you get?  What have you tried?  You should put some effort into your question!  I added the link to the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't NEED to use wxSQLite.  You can simply call the SQLite API directly from your code.  It takes an hour or two to get familiar with the API, but then it does everything you need without worrying about linking your build to yet another package.

The SQLite API is a library.  There are several ways you can 'install' it.  I have noticed that the SQLite site is a bit vague on this question.  Here is what I do.

Download the zip containing the prebuilt DLL from http://sqlite.org/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3071000.zip

This will give you the DLL, which should go in the folder where your executable runs.

This will also give the the export deefinition file ( .def  ).  This has to be converted to a .lib file so that it can be linked to.  You do this using the lib utility.

You also need the sqlite3.h header file, which is included in the amalgamation downloaded from http://sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3071000.zip

If all this seems like a lot of trouble, you can alternatively use the amalgamation.  Simply download the amalgamation and add the two files to your project.  The downside with this is that you will have to build the SQLite code over and over again,slowing your build process, and the entire code will be statically linked to every executable.  Nowadays builds run on modern computers so quickly that the cost of using the amalgamation is well worth the gain in simplicity.  These days, I never use the DLL.

Comment: Thank you ravenspoint. Do i have to install anything to call SQLite API?

Comment: @fex I have describes what needs to be done to call the API in the body of my answer.  BTW, I no longer use the DLL since moderns compilers are so fast that the cost to compile the amalgamation in every build is well worth the simplicity of not worrying about installing a DLL.

Answer (score 3):

Of course one could use the SQLite API directly as ravenspoint pointed out, but wxSQLite3 makes it easier to integrate SQLite databases with wxWidgets-based C++ applications. The wxSQLite3 API is similar to JDBC and ODBC. wxSQLite3 takes care of converting wxString objects to and from UTF-8, one of the 2 encodings (UTF-8 or UTF-16) expected by SQLite; wxSQLite3 supports creating user defined functions as C++ classes; and adds several other features like backup and restore of databases, value collections, support for different date and time value representations and so on. wxSQLite3 can load the SQLite DLL at runtime without requiring a link library if you prefer, it's just setting a compile time flag.

Adding wxSQLite3 to a project is simple: either create a DLL or static library using the build files (including VC++ 2008 solution) coming with wxSQLite3, or just add the single C++ source file and few header files to your own project.

In case of difficulties ask your questions on the [wxWidgets developer forum](http://forum.wxwidgets.org).

Comment: " wxSQLite3 takes care of converting wxString objects to and from UTF-8 used by SQLite"  Why do you say that SQLite uses UTF-8?  It stores whatever is passed to it - Ascii, UTF-8, UTF-16, anything.  No conversions are ever required.  In a Unicode build you would, of course, use the UTF16 API for convenience.  IMHO wxSQLite3 is a solution to a non-existent problem.

Comment: SQLite expects that strings are encoded in UTF-8 or UTF-16. You are right that SQLite doesn't force you to use Unicode but if you don't take care of appropriate conversion you may end up with SQLite database files which can't be interchanged between different applications without problems. For a stand-alone application this might not impose a problem but quite often it does, i.e. if you use external tools for managing a SQLite database in addition to your own application. - wxSQLite3 can simplify accessing SQLite databases from wxWidgets applications. If you feel different just don't use it.

Comment: It is incorrect to say that SQLite uses UTF-8, and suggest that a conversion between UTF16 and UTF8 is required   Please edit your answer.

Comment: I adjusted the formulation in my first answer. I didn't suggest a conversion between UTF-16 and UTF-8 is required, but it's certainly recommended to convert different encodings to/from UTF-8 (or UTF-16). For an ANSI build of wxWidgets wxSQLite3 does exactly this (I know it's not that important anymore for wxWidgets 2.9.x). Enforcing a portable encoding is just one feature of wxSQLite3. Providing a C++ like interface to SQLite is more important for most users of wxSQLite3. Certainly each developer may decide for himself whether to use or not use wxSQLite3.